# Auto generated Gridview - Change columns width

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

i'm in a trouble!

I'm generating a lot of gridviews dinamically, with dinamic values to columns.
The columns are ever the same.

I want to know how can i set the size of this columns.

That's my code, with my effort.

```
    private void generateControls( List<List<DataRow>> grids)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (List<DataRow> lst in grids)
        {
            dt = lst.CopyToDataTable();

            GridView grv = new GridView();
            grv.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#cccccc");
            grv.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;

            grv.Width = new Unit("100%");
            //grv.RowStyle.Wrap = false;
            grv.RowStyle.Width = new Unit("100%");

            grv.ID = "grid_view" + i;
            grv.DataSource = dt;
            grv.DataBind();

          /*  grv.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("5%");
            grv.Columns[1].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("7%");
            grv.Columns[2].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("12%");
            grv.Columns[3].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("12%");
            grv.Columns[4].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("7%");
            grv.Columns[5].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("7%");
            grv.Columns[6].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("23%");
            grv.Columns[7].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("22%");
            grv.Columns[8].ItemStyle.Width = new Unit("5%");*/

            Label lblBlankLines = new Label();
            lblBlankLines.Text = "<br />";

            Panel panelGrid = new Panel();
            panelGrid.ID = "panel_grid" + i;


            Label lblTipo = new Label();
            string tipoOcorrencia = lst[0]["Ocorrência"].ToString();

           /* 
            * Capitalized
            * TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("pt-BR", false).TextInfo;

            string novoTipoOcorrencia = myTI.ToTitleCase(tipoOcorrencia);*/

            int quantidade = lst.Count;
            lblTipo.Text = " - " + tipoOcorrencia + ": " + quantidade;


            LinkButton lkBtn = new LinkButton();
            lkBtn.ID = "link_button" + i;
            lkBtn.Text = "Exibir | Ocultar";
            lkBtn.Attributes["onClick"] = "javascript:return ocultaGrid('" + panelGrid.ID + "'), false";

            panel_status.Controls.Add(lblBlankLines);
            panel_status.Controls.Add(lkBtn);
            panel_status.Controls.Add(lblTipo);


            panelGrid.Controls.Add(grv);

            panel_status.Controls.Add(panelGrid);

            panel_status.DataBind();

            i++;
        }
    }
```

I've tried to get the columns, but i got an error, telling me an invalid index access.
How can i access my columns in that gridview?

Comment: string tipoOcorrencia = lst[0]["Ocorrência"].ToString(); I would not use characters like this "ê" in programming. Change that to a simple "e" and see what happens.

Comment: Also, do tell on which line you get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the RowDataBound EventHandler:

Count your indexes and make sure you are not trying to access a non-existent column as well.

See link for an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178296(v=vs.100).ASPX

grv.RowDataBound += grv_RowDataBound;

```
    private void grv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {

                   e.Row.Cells[0].Width = new Unit("5%");
                   e.Row.Cells[1].Width = new Unit("7%");
                   e.Row.Cells[2].Width = new Unit("12%");
                   e.Row.Cells[3].Width = new Unit("12%");
                   e.Row.Cells[4].Width = new Unit("7%");
                   e.Row.Cells[5].Width = new Unit("7%");
                   e.Row.Cells[6].Width = new Unit("23%");
                   e.Row.Cells[7].Width = new Unit("22%");
                   e.Row.Cells[8].Width = new Unit("5%"); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: It works!!! You really saved my day!

Just to improve, if you have setted any value to "grv.RowStyle.Width" you must to delete it to works. =)